# Formatting an equation correctly

Tags: support

My [answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/2955/225) was migrated from English.stackexchange.com.

The equation in it looked bad then, but it was edited and it looks worse now. The "proportional to" sign (which has a similar shape to the Greek letter alpha) has a v "del" symbol instead.

Is there a formatting language subset that might fix it? How can I get this to look more like the equation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herdan%27s_law ?

Comment: Uhm, good point. I'll think about this and see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks, @Alenanno. Looking forward to it.

Comment: Ok, for now I have no way to do this. I'll be leaving this question like this in case a future solution comes. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: Do we have enough equations in quantitative or computational linguistics to warrant enabling Mathjax here?